# Efficicient algorithm to check if $az+1=(xz+1)(yz+1)$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility, factoring, computational-complexity

Given two positive integers $a$ and $z$ with $z$ prime, consider the problem of determining whether the integer $az+1$ can be factored as $az+1=(xz+1)(yz+1)$, where $x, y$ are positive integers and $xz+1$ is prime. This problem can be solved by checking if $yz+1 \ | \ az+1$ for some integer $y$, $yz+1 \le \sqrt{az+1}$.

Trial division however is too slow when $a/z$ is large. Is there an efficient algorithm for solving this problem or a particular case. (Note that we are not interested in finding factors of $az+1$, only to determine if it can be factored this way).

A related but different question is here [Prove that the diophantine equation $(xz+1)(yz+1)=az^{3} +1$ has no solutions in positive integers $x, y, z$ with $z>a^{2} +2a$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3842292/prove-that-the-diophantine-equation-xz1yz1-az3-1-has-no-solutions-in)

Comment: $az+1=(xz+1)(yz+1)=xyz^2+xz+yz+1$, $a=xyz+x+y$, so a restatement of the question is whether, given $a,z$, there is an efficient way to decide whether there exist $x,y$ such that $a=xyz+x+y$.

Comment: parity helps one of $x,y$ being even forces the other to be the same parity as $a$

Comment: perhaps it help to note that $(x+1)(y+1) \equiv a+1 \  ($mod$ \ z-1)$

Comment: How large numbers will there be?

Comment: $a/z$ is arbitrarily large. Take $z = 3$ and $a = 10^{1000}$

Comment: So $a$ can be huge. Will $z$ be more modest?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll give a heuristic argument for the following claim: *any algorithm that solves this problem cannot be faster than factoring $az+1$.*

From there it is well known what the asymptotic complexity is, plus what algorithms are actually faster when implemented in a programming language and so on.

Consider the first few cases with small $z$:

$z=2$

The algorithm returns true if and only if $az+1$ is composite. I proved this a couple days ago [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4077450/883143).

$z=3$

Let the factorization of $az+1$ be the following:

$$az+1=\prod_i p_i^{a_i}\prod_i q_i^{b_i}$$

Where $p_i\equiv 1 \mod 3$ and $q_i\equiv 2 \mod 3$. We have that $\sum b_i \equiv 0 \mod 2$ since $az+1\equiv 1 \mod 3$. The factorization is impossible again if $az+1$ is prime but also in the case where $\sum b_i = 2$ and there are no $a_i$ i.e. when it is the product of two primes $\equiv 2 \mod 3$. It's easy to see that all other cases allow you to group the primes into two factors that are $\equiv 1 \mod 3$, all of which get you a valid factorization.

The case $z=4$ is very similar to the previous one. But when $\varphi(z)$ starts getting larger it gets more complicated. The case $z=5$ is as follows:

Let

$$az+1=\prod_i p_i^{a_i}\prod_i q_i^{b_i}\prod_i r_i^{c_i}\prod_i s_i^{d_i}$$

Where the classes of prime numbers are those congruent to $1,2,3,4$ mod 5 respectively. Let also $A=\sum_i a_i$ and the same for the other three residue classes. Then $az+1$ is of the form $(5x+1)(5y+1)$ when all of the following are false:

- It is prime;
- $A=C=D=0$ and $B=4$;
- $A=D=0$ and $B=C=1$;
- $A=C=0$ and $B=2$ and $D=1$;

As you can see, these are increasingly complicated statements about the prime factorizations of $az+1$. So I don't think your question can be answered faster than actually factoring it.

Comment: Suppose we restrict both $z$ and $xz+1$ to be prime, can we create a faster algorithm compared to factoring or doing trial divisions on $az+1$ ?

Comment: @DavidJones I don't think the prime factorization of $z$ matters for this problem. Plus you can't just declare $xz+1$ to be prime, you need to find an $x$ that makes it prime. So I don't see how either of those would help.

Comment: I meant modifying the question such that $z$ and $xz+1$ are prime. Given a prime $z$, and a positive integer $a$, is it possible to find some positive integers $x$ and $y$ such that $az+1=(xz+1)(yz+1)$ and $xz+1$ is prime?

Answer (score 1):

As **GerryMyerson** writes, "$az+1=(xz+1)(yz+1)=xyz^2+xz+yz+1,\ a=xyz+x+y,$ so a restatement of the question is whether, given $a,z,$ there is an efficient way to decide whether there exist $x,y$ such that $a=xyz+x+y.$"

Then, a restatement of this is whether, given $a,z$ and $a=qz+r,$ there exist $x,y$ such that $xy=q$ and $x+y=r.$ But this corresponds to solving $x(r-x)=q$ which has solutions
$$
2x = r \pm \sqrt{r^2-4q}.
$$
Thus, we need to decide whether $r^2-4q$ is a square number, say $s^2.$

Now, $r^2-4q=s^2$ is equivalent to $(r+s)(r-s)=4q$ which means that we need to find all factorizations of $4q.$

Comment: It seems like this only finds solutions with $x+y < z$, if you use $a=xyz+x+y$ and $a=qz+r$ to conclude that $xy=q$ and $x+y=r$.

Comment: @MishaLavrov. Ah, you're right. So this is not a complete solution, but still it might be helpful, so I won't delete this answer.

Comment: works well when the prime factorization of $q$ is known before-hand and $x+y<z$

Answer (score 1):

Taking in account **GerryMyerson** comment, easily to get the system in the form of
\begin{cases}
az+1=(xz+1)(yz+1) = 1+ z(x+y) + z^2xy\\
a=xyz+x+y=(xz+1)y+x=(yz+1)x+y\\
x\le y\\
a,x,y,z\in\mathbb N,\tag1
\end{cases}
where $\;x,y\;$ are unknowns and $\;a,z\;$ are parameters.

Denote $\;s=x+y,\;$ then
$$4(az+1) = 4+4zs+z^2s^2-z^2s^2+4z^2x(s-x) =(zs+2)^2-z^2(s-2x)^2,$$
$$4(a-s) = z(s^2-(s-2x)^2),$$
$$a = zx(s-x)+s,$$
\begin{cases}
y=s-x\\[4pt]
s\in\left\{z\left\lfloor\dfrac{2\sqrt{1+az}-2}{z^2}\right\rfloor+(k-1)z+(a \mod z),\; k\in\mathbb N\right\}\cap\{1,2\dots a\}\\[4pt]
2x=s-\sqrt{s^2-\dfrac{4a-4s}z}.\tag2
\end{cases}

Therefore, the integer variable $\;s\;$ should change the values with the step $\;z.\;$

If $\;z\;$ is too small, then can be used analysis on the unused simple residue classes.

For example, the parity anlysis of $(1)$ gives the next additional constraints.

- If $\;\mathbf{(2\!\not|\;z)\wedge(2\!\not|\;a)},\;$ then $\;(2\,|\;az+1),\;(2\!\not|\;x)\vee(2\!\not|\;y).\;$
- If $\;\mathbf{(2\!\not|\;z)\wedge(2\,|\;a)},\;$ then $\;(2\!\not|\;az+1),\;(2\,|\;x)\wedge(2\,|\;y).\;$
- If $\;\mathbf{(2\,|\;z)\wedge(2\!\not|\;a)},\;$ then $\;(2\!\not|\;az+1),\;(2\,|\;x+y).\;$
- If $\;\mathbf{(2\,|\;z)\wedge(2\,|\;a)},\;$ then $\;(2\!\not|\;az+1),\;(2\!\,\not|\;x+y).\;$

Similar schemes allow to improve the computational complexity of the algorithm.

However, there are not a good simple algorithm for big numbers.